# How to create codeigniter dynamic menu from single table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a table like this 
Table name:menu

```
Id menu submenu      childmenu
1. Oil. Edible.      Coconut oil
2. Oil. Edible.      Sunflowe oil
3. Oil. Non edible.  Deepa oil
4. Oil  non edible.  Coconut oil
```

My expected output is

```
Oil 
 Edible
   Coconut oil
   Sunflower oil
 Non edible
   Deepa oil
   Coconut oil
```

How to create a menu like this. Thanks for your answers

Comment: I need looping in my view page. I don't have an idea how to create a model and view like this

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the user has put in no effort to solve his/her problem.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started. The rest is rather self-explanatory if you've read the docs (which you should).

```
$array = array(
    array(
        'id' => '1',
        'menu' => 'Oil',
        'submenu' => 'editable',
        'childmenu' => 'coco oil'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => '2',
        'menu' => 'Oil',
        'submenu' => 'editable',
        'childmenu' => 'sunflower'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => '3',
        'menu' => 'Oil2',
        'submenu' => 'noneditable',
        'childmenu' => 'deepa'
    ),
);
// CONTROLLER
$_data = array();
// $array will come from model result_array()
foreach ($array as $item) {
    $_data[$item['menu']][$item['submenu']][] = $item['childmenu'];
}
// send $_data to view
// VIEW
foreach ($_data as $menu => $submenu) {
    echo '<i>' . $menu . '</i><br>';
    foreach ($submenu as $name => $childmenu) {
        echo '<strong>' . $name . '</strong><br>';
        foreach ($childmenu as $item) {
            echo $item . '<br>';
        }
    }
}
```

Essentially I rearrange the array to be more friendly to work with. This way it prevents us from having to check *specific* submenus in a foreach later on in the view.